# weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.AnnotationProcessException ( weblogic 12c and spring5 java based config)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, weblogic12c

```
Hi am new to spring mvc java based configuration,

i get this error when i run this app on weblogic 12c,

weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.AnnotationProcessException: [HTTP:101396]Either the urlPatterns or the value attribute in the WebServlet annotation MUST be present.
```

However the same project runs as expected in tomcat. so what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution , i realized this had to be an xml based error the web.xml version i used was 3.1 , i had to downgrade my web.xml to 2.4 , this is the thread that helped me  https://community.oracle.com/message/14757320#14757320 , hope someone finds this useful.